# Matlab coder reallocation

Tags: matlab, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation, matlab-coder, codegen

I have some code like this in my matlab function:

```
for i = init:end
    a= [a, char(zeros(size(a))]
    a= func(a)
    a = a(a~=0)
end
```

So, in each step of the loop, you first double the size of a, apply some random function to it, and then remove everything that is a zero.

Now, I want to run coder on this to eventually make it into c code. Of course, it gives me allocation errors.

Allowing dynamically allocated arrays doesn't help. I can't simply use different names for my variables either because it is in a for loop.

Comment: what is the type of elements of a? did you display the result to see what you are getting from one iteration to another?

Comment: As I said, this is an example code. a could be anything. The code works in matlab, but coder is having trouble making this into a c code.

Comment: you may consider running the example code and make sure it is working too, so that you get the best suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

This may come a year late however something like:

```
function a = foobar(init,ub)
coder.varsize('a',[1,Inf]);
a = 1;
for i = init:ub
    a = [a, ones(size(a))];
    a = sin(a);
    a = a(a~=0);
end

>> codegen foobar -args {1,1} -report
```

works for me in R2014a.

When you are trying to grow an array, it may be necessary to use `coder.varsize` in order to tell MATLAB Coder that the array is going to change size.  In many cases MATLAB Coder can figure this out without using `coder.varsize` so it is best to try without it first and then add it in if errors are encountered.